# I can't access the properties of an object even though I can see it's contents

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

This code used to work just fine when I was using bootstrap's way of dropdown menus.. now that I switched to conventional I dont know why I'm getting this problem.  Why can't I access the properties??  Driving me nuts here

HTML

```
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="client" ng-change="clientSelect(client)">
        <option value="">--- Please Select ---</option>
        <option ng-repeat="client in clientList" value="{{client}}">{{client.clientName}}</option>
    </select>
```

Angular/Javascript

```
$scope.clientSelect = function (client) {
  console.log(client);
  console.log(client.clientName);  //is undefined
  console.log(client.clientId);  //is undefined
}
```

Ouput:

```
{"clientId":102,"clientName":"Testing"}  //i clearly see the properties here...
UsersController.js:130 undefined
UsersController.js:131 undefined
```

EDIT: when I console.log($scope.clientList) it's fine.. the object of the first item in the array looks like this:

0: Object
     $$hashKey: "object:254"
     clientId: 102
     clientName: "Testing"
     **_proto**: Object

Comment: Put a `debugger` right before the first `console.log` and check what actually is there

Comment: You should be using `ng-options` to populate the select

Comment: thanks guys will look into this right now.. particularly the ng-options

Comment: @charlietfl it worked!  you can put it as the answer so i can give you credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access properties, because the `client` you get from ng-repeat is a `string`.

Check the console log of this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7bRVi95qoB5I2OcbFgzg?p=preview) I created with your code. You will see that the first `consol.log(client)` is actually logs out this string: `{"clientId":102,"clientName":"Testing 1"}`. Therefore, it doesn't have any properties.

From the [select docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select):

> Note that the value of a select directive used without ngOptions is always a string. When the model needs to be bound to a non-string value, you must either explictly convert it using a directive (see example below) or use ngOptions to specify the set of options. This is because an option element can only be bound to string values at present.

Consider using the [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive instead of `<select>` with ng-repeat.